# old display value is kept on switching CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have three articles which I want to display separately based on screensize.

**Article 1** should only be visible when < 600

**Article 2** should be visible between 600 and 900

**Article 3** should be visible when > 900

Here is the CSS declaration:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stijlen/r0755939basis.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="stijlen/r0755939medium.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="stijlen/r0755939groot.css" />
```

All articles are of the following format:

```
    <article id="article1"><p>article1</p></article>
```

I have applied the following CSS with article[number] different in each stylesheet:

```
article {
    display: none;
}

#article1{
    display: block;
}
```

What happens is that only < 600 is correct. The bigger one displays 1 and 2, and the final one displays all of them.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: You aren't using any `max-width` values in your media queries so when the screen is > 900px all of the CSS files will be used, therefore all of the articles will be `display: block`.

Comment: specificity - an id beats an element, therefore as you override only when the screen gets bigger (and have no upper limit) each article will show as your screen grows (and won't hide again as each stylesheet matches the condition).  Either add an upper limit to your stylesheet conditions or override the previous style in the next stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-width` and `min-width` conditionally

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stijlen/r0755939basis.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="stijlen/r0755939medium.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px)" href="stijlen/r0755939groot.css" />
```

Comment: I'm actually stupid. I forgot that multiple CSS files can be in the memory at the same time. This solves it. Thanks.

Comment: @user6875529 welcome mate. That's true,little bit mistake make more confuse then big one

Answer (score 1):

simply add media in your css file and that's it.

```
<article id="article1"><p>article1</p></article>
<article id="article2"><p>article2</p></article>
<article id="article3"><p>article3</p></article>
```

CSS

```
article{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #article1{display: block;}
}
@media (min-width:600px)and (max-width:900px){
    #article2{display: block;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    #article3{display: block;}
}
```